# Capturing first word and number in string

Tags: php, regex

I have a sample string such as

`September 14-20, 26, 28-30, October 1-8, 10, 11, 15-20, 24, November 25, 28-30`

When using `(?:^|(?:[.!?]\s))(^[^\d]*(\d+))(\w+)`, it doesn't capture the first word and number individually.

[image]

How can I capture *only* `September` and `14` in a single expression?

Comment: Does `^(\w+)\s(\d+)` do what you're after?

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, it does. Please add it as answer.

Comment: The reason get 2 separate groups for 1 and 4 is after \d+ you match \w+ and the whole pattern should be matched so \d+ gives up  1 match and \w+ matches 1 time. You could also match only characters for the month `^([a-zA-Z]+) (\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/n6sNWR/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple version (I'm not a regex person) which I can understand is...

```
^(\w+)\s(\d+)
```

Basically - start at the begining(`^`) then 1+ occurrences of a word character (`(\w+)`) space and then a sequence of digits (`(\d+)`).

In PHP:

```
$str = 'September 14-20, 26, 28-30, October 1-8, 10, 11, 15-20, 24, November 25, 28-30';
preg_match('/(\w+)\s(\d+)/', $str, $pieces);
$first_month = $pieces[1];
$first_day = $pieces[2];
var_dump($first_month, $first_day);
```

https://3v4l.org/USVNa

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
(?:^|(?:[.!?]\s))^([^\d]*)(\d+)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to match just one occurrence anywhere in your sample string then remove the `/g` flag:

```
/\w+\s\d+/
```

Result of `26, 28-30, October 1-8, 10, 11, 15-20, 24, November 25, 28-30`

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/Nofzab/2

Using `September 14-20, 26, 28-30, October 1-8, 10, 11, 15-20, 24, November 25, 28-30` would get you `September 14`

Comment: I am very interested in hearing why someone disagrees with this answer...

Comment: Not my downvote, but I think the OP wants to capture the first word and number individually.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Hmm, I see what OP is asking now, thanks!